Rust mockall crate, no method named `returning`
I am using mockall crate for unittest.
#[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
pub trait Reader {
    fn next_data(&mut self) -> &Data;
}


impl Reader for TestReader {
    fn next_data(&mut self) -> &Data {
        let data: &Data = &self.data[self.index];
        self.index += 1;
        data
    }
}



fn test_reader() {
    let data_iter: IntoIter<Data> = (some vector Vec<Data>).into_iter();
    let mut reader = MockReader::new();
    reader
        .expect_next_data()
        .times(2)
        .returning(move || data_iter.clone().next().is_some());

This is the error message I receive
error[E0599]: no method named `returning` found for mutable reference `&mut __mock_MockReader_Reader::__next_data::Expectation` in the current scope
   --> src/tests/test_data.rs:177:14
    |
174 | /         reader
175 | |             .expect_next_data()
176 | |             .times(2)
177 | |             .returning(move || data_iter.clone().next().is_some());
    | |             -^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut Expectation`
    | |_____________|
    | 


How should I deal with this? The returning should work based on the mockall document. I have no idea why it says method not found.

Do you think the closure returns the same type as next_data?

@fdan I'm pretty new to rust, so I might have mistake at syntax, but I think it should return the same type. Would that be related to returning method not found error?

The closure returns a bool, not a reference to Data. Anyway, it's not related. You should read the official documentation for returning references. For immutable references, you have to use return_const.

The next_data method returns a reference, rather than a static value.  A returning method wouldn't work in this case, because its closure would need to return a reference to a value which is probably constructed by the closure itself.  So for methods that return references, you must use .return_const instead of .returning.

It works for mutable references, though. I've never used that crate, but there seems to be another reason for not supporting returning.

Well, I wrote that crate, and I'm telling you that that's exactly the reason.  Full details at https://docs.rs/mockall/latest/mockall/#reference-return-values .
